# How do I export table data from a Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms, export

I recently created a Cognito form that included a table field. When I view and export the entries the table data within individual entries is not included in the output. How do I ensure the table data can be viewed and / or exported?

Answer (score 1):

To export table data from your Cognito Form:

1. From the Entries page, select the entry or entries that you want to export.
2. Select the Actions option, then select All Fields.
3. The table data will be contained in its own worksheet within the Excel file.

Comment: Thank you. I just exported the entries as per your instructions and it worked perfectly.